# ContentThemeTransition on DataContext change

Tags: xaml, animation, win-universal-app

In a Universal Windows Platform app a **ContentThemeTransition** can be applied to a ContentControl to **animate the appearance of a new child control**.

Is there a way to get the same visual behavior (animation) when simply **changing the DataContext on the existing child control** (rather that creating a new child control instance each time, which seems wasteful)?

Comment: Have you tried using the [DataContextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx) event to fire off the same transition?

Comment: How do I 'fire off' the same transition?

Comment: Wait, now that I think about it, you shouldn't even need that amigo, you're setting your ContentThemeTransition on the `Blah.ContentTransitions` as opposed to just `Blah.Transitions` right? If so it should do it by itself when the databound content changes.

Comment: Actually, it does sometimes but not everytime. I haven't been able to determine the difference. That's why I was looking into triggering it explicitly.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for EntranceThemeAnimation? I want to say that's what I did last time I did this to get what I think you're shooting for.